# sliding window std filter for a one channel image

Tags: c++, image-processing, intel-ipp

I would like to apply "std filter" with a fixed patch size to a single channel image.
That is I want `out[i,j]` to equal the std of the pixels values at a neighborhood around `img[i,j]`.

For those of you who are familiar with Matlab, I'm looking for the equivalent of

```
>> out = nlfilter( img, [P P], @std );
```

Is there a way to do this using `ippi` functions?

I came across [`ippiMean_StdDev`](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ippi/ippi_ch11/functn_Mean_StdDev.html) but it seems to work for a single window, and not a sliding window (returning a scalar value rather than an array).
I also saw [`ippiRectStdDev`](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ippi/ippi_ch11/functn_RectStdDev.html) but the manual states this function is for integral images - and I don't see how this applies in my case.

Does anyone has a working example or a more detailed manual for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured it out.

1. input image must be in uint8 format
2. need to allocate 2 buffers (32bit float and 64bit float in my case)
3. sizes of arrays:
   input size `H`x`W`
   filter size, `P`x`P`
   result size `H-P+1`x`W-P+1`
   intermidate buffers (32f and 64f) sizes `H+1`x`W+1` (note the plus one for integral image boundary!)

   ```
   // first, compute integral and sqIntegral image 
   IppiSize sz; sz.width = W; sz.height = H;
   ippiSqrIntegral_8u32f64f_C1R( uint8ImgPtr, W*sizeof(unsigned char), 
       d32ImgPtr, (W+1)*sizeof(float), 
       d64ImgPtr, (W+1)*sizeof(double), 
       sz, 0, 0 );
   // using the integral images compute the std filter result
   IppiRect rect = { 0, 0, P, P };
   IppiSize dsz; dsz.width = W-P+1; dsz.height = H-P+1;
   ippiRectStdDev_32f_C1R( d32ImgPtr, (W+1)*sizeof(float), 
       d64ImgPtr, (W+1)*sizeof(double), 
       dstPtr, (W-P+1)*sizeof(float), dsz, rect );
   ```